# Contact form in HTML/PHP to my e-mail

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a simple contact form in HTML with PHP script for my website. Internet is full of examples, but they usually are too simple or too complicated.

Here's my form in HTML and I need PHP script for it.

```
        <form action="send.php" method="POST" id="form">
              <label for="latitude">Lat. &deg;N:</label>
              <input id="latitude" name="latitude" type="text" />
              <label for="longitude">Long. &deg;E:</label>
              <input id="longitude" name="longitude" type="text" />
              <label for="desc">Description:</label>
              <textarea style="resize:none" name="desc" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
              <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
              <input type="text" name="mail" /><br>
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
```

1. It should contain `charset=utf-8` to display all of my language's diacritics in a message.
2. It should have a validation if ALL fields are not empty. E-mail validation is not needed.
3. It should inform in a very simple way `Message send!` or `Error, try again.`

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Instead if/when you attempt to write the code yourself, you can come ask for help on very specific problems you've encountered.

Comment: If these are your requirements, I can't imaging you have found an example that was too simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@EWit is right... You can't really use Stack Overflow like this. However, the PHP below should work. Try and pull it apart so you can learn from it. Cheers

```
<?PHP

define('kOptional', true);
define('kMandatory', false);

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
ini_set('track_errors', true);

function DoStripSlashes($fieldValue)  { 

 if ( function_exists( 'get_magic_quotes_gpc' ) && get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) { 
  if (is_array($fieldValue) ) { 
   return array_map('DoStripSlashes', $fieldValue); 
  } else { 
   return trim(stripslashes($fieldValue)); 
  } 
 } else { 
  return $fieldValue; 
 } 
}

function FilterCChars($theString) {
 return preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F]/', '', $theString);
}

function CheckEmail($email, $optional) {
 if ( (strlen($email) == 0) && ($optional === kOptional) ) {
  return true;
  } elseif ( preg_match("/^([\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+@((((([a-z0-9]{1}[a-z0-9\-]{0,62}[a-z0-9]{1})|[a-z])\.)+[a-z]{2,6})|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(\:\d{1,5})?)$/i", $email) == 1 ) {
  return true;
 } else {
  return false;
 }
}

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
 $clientIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
 $clientIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$FTGlatitude = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['latitude'] );
$FTGlongitude = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['longitude'] );
$FTGdesc = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['desc'] );
$FTGmail = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['mail'] );
$FTGsubmit = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['submit'] );

$validationFailed = false;

if (!CheckEmail($FTGmail, kMandatory)) {
 $FTGErrorMessage['mail'] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
 $validationFailed = true;
}


if ($validationFailed === true) {

 $errorPage = '<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>Error</title></head><body>Errors found: <!--VALIDATIONERROR--></body></html>';

 $errorPage = str_replace('<!--FIELDVALUE:latitude-->', $FTGlatitude, $errorPage);
 $errorPage = str_replace('<!--FIELDVALUE:longitude-->', $FTGlongitude, $errorPage);
 $errorPage = str_replace('<!--FIELDVALUE:desc-->', $FTGdesc, $errorPage);
 $errorPage = str_replace('<!--FIELDVALUE:mail-->', $FTGmail, $errorPage);
 $errorPage = str_replace('<!--FIELDVALUE:submit-->', $FTGsubmit, $errorPage);
 $errorPage = str_replace('<!--ERRORMSG:mail-->', $FTGErrorMessage['mail'], $errorPage);

 $errorList = @implode("<br />\n", $FTGErrorMessage);
 $errorPage = str_replace('<!--VALIDATIONERROR-->', $errorList, $errorPage);

 echo $errorPage;

}

if ( $validationFailed === false ) {

 $emailSubject = FilterCChars("Website Contact");

 $emailBody = chunk_split( base64_encode( "<html>\n"
  . "<head>\n"
  . "<title></title>\n"
  . "</head>\n"
  . "<body>\n"
  . "Latitude : $FTGlatitude<br />\n"
  . "Longitude : $FTGlongitude<br />\n"
  . "Desc : " . nl2br( $FTGdesc ) . "<br />\n"
  . "Mail : $FTGmail<br />\n"
  . "Submit : $FTGsubmit<br />\n"
  . "</body>\n"
  . "</html>\n"
  . "" ) )
  . "\n";
  $emailTo = 'Contact <your@email.com>';

  $emailFrom = FilterCChars("$FTGmail");

  $emailHeader = "From: $emailFrom\n"
   . "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
   . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n"
   . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n"
   . "\n";

  mail($emailTo, $emailSubject, $emailBody, $emailHeader);

$successPage = '<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>Success</title></head><body>Form submitted successfully. It will be reviewed soon.</body></html>';

$successPage = str_replace('<!--FIELDVALUE:latitude-->', $FTGlatitude, $successPage);
$successPage = str_replace('<!--FIELDVALUE:longitude-->', $FTGlongitude, $successPage);
$successPage = str_replace('<!--FIELDVALUE:desc-->', $FTGdesc, $successPage);
$successPage = str_replace('<!--FIELDVALUE:mail-->', $FTGmail, $successPage);
$successPage = str_replace('<!--FIELDVALUE:submit-->', $FTGsubmit, $successPage);

echo $successPage;

}

?>
```

Comment: @Helios Great! I only validated the email field as I wasn't sure what would be inputted into the other fields. Check out some tutorials and you should be able to add validation in other areas if you want.